# RxJava nested Zip operation not returning

Tags: java, android, rx-java, observable

I've created this long observable with several nested observables and two `Zip` operators.

My issue is that the outer most `Zip` operator never has its function called... in this case it's `Func5(...)`.

I am able to debug the nested `Zip` operator and see the `Func6(...)` return the `Map<String, Object>` but then nothing happens.  No `onNext`, `onError`, or `onComplete` from the `subscriber`.

What am I missing here?

The `Zip` operators return an observable so I assumed nesting was ok.

```
Observable.zip(
                UserApi.doThis(someValue)
                        .flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<typeA1>>() {
                            @Override
                            public Observable<typeA1> call(String photoId) {
                                return UserApi.getUserPhotoData(photoId);
                            }
                        }),
                UserApi.doThat(),
                UserApi.doSomething(settingName0),
                InstitutionApi.getThis(someValue),
                Observable.zip(
                        InstitutionApi.getInstitutionSetting(settingName1).onErrorReturn(new Func1<Throwable, typeB1>() {
                            @Override
                            public typeB1 call(Throwable throwable) {
                                return new typeB1(...);
                            }
                        }),
                        InstitutionApi.getInstitutionSetting(settingName2).onErrorReturn(new Func1<Throwable, typeB1>() {
                            @Override
                            public typeB1 call(Throwable throwable) {
                                return new typeB1(...);
                            }
                        }),
                        InstitutionApi.getInstitutionSetting(settingName3).onErrorReturn(new Func1<Throwable, typeB1>() {
                            @Override
                            public typeB1 call(Throwable throwable) {
                                return new typeB1(...);
                            }
                        }),
                        InstitutionApi.getInstitutionContentString(stringName1).onErrorReturn(new Func1<Throwable, typeB2>() {
                            @Override
                            public typeB2 call(Throwable throwable) {
                                return null;
                            }
                        }),
                        InstitutionApi.getInstitutionSetting(settingName4).onErrorReturn(new Func1<Throwable, typeB1>() {
                            @Override
                            public typeB1 call(Throwable throwable) {
                                return new typeB1(...);
                            }
                        }),
                        InstitutionApi.getInstitutionSetting(settingName5).onErrorReturn(new Func1<Throwable, typeB1>() {
                            @Override
                            public typeB1 call(Throwable throwable) {
                                return new typeB1(...);
                            }
                        }),
                        new Func6<typeB1, typeB1, typeB1, typeB2, typeB1, typeB1, Map<String, Object>>() {
                            @Override
                            public Map<String, Object> call(typeB1 r0, typeB1 r1, typeB1 r2,
                                                                 typeB2 r3, typeB1 r4, typeB1 r5) {
                                Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                                try {
                                   // do things
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    return null;
                                }
                                return map;
                            }
                        }),
                new Func5<typeA1, typeA2, typeA3, typeA4, Map<String, Object>, EndReturnType>() {
                    @Override
                    public EndReturnType call(typeA1 r0, typeA2 r1, typeA3  r2, typeA4 r3, Map<String, Object> r4) {

                        EndReturnType ert = new EndReturnType ();
                        // do things

                        return ert;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Did you confirm that all Observables emit a value? You can use `doOnNext` to debug them.

Comment: I deleted my previous comments because you were correct zsxwing.  The function `InstitutionApi.getThis()` was missing the `onNext` and `onComplete` functions.  Thank you Sir/Ma'am!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As zsxwing mentioned in the comments, one of my functions was not returning a value due to a missing `onNext` function.